# How to compare and show if any changes in historical data in AWS Athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I have a table where historical data is stored. The sample structure of the table is like,

| id | config | userid | team | createdon |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "config-01" | "user-01" | "Dev" | "2022:08:28" |
| 2 | "config-02" | "user-01" | "Dev" | "2022:08:27" |
| 3 | "config-01" | "user-01" | "Dev" | "2022:08:26" |
| 4 | "config-01" | "user-01" | "QA" | "2022:08:25" |
| 5 | "config-01" | "user-01" | "QA" | "2022:08:24" |
| 6 | "config-20" | "user-01" | "QA" | "2022:08:23" |
| 7 | "config-01" | "user-01" | "QA" | "2022:08:22" |
| 8 | "config-01" | "user-01" | "Prod" | "2022:08:21" |
| 9 | "config-01" | "user-01" | "Prod" | "2022:08:20" |
| 10 | "config-11" | "user-02" | "Prod" | "2022:08:19" |
| 11 | "config-15" | "user-02" | "Prod" | "2022:08:18" |

Now, I need to query data based on user-id, so first 9 rows will be taken for user-id "user-01". From these 9 rows I need to take latest two rows(based on createdon) of each team. So the table as of now looks like this,

| id | config | userid | team | createdon |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "config-01" | "user-01" | "Dev" | "2022:08:28" |
| 2 | "config-02" | "user-01" | "Dev" | "2022:08:27" |
| 4 | "config-01" | "user-01" | "QA" | "2022:08:28" |
| 5 | "config-01" | "user-01" | "QA" | "2022:08:27" |
| 8 | "config-01" | "user-01" | "Prod" | "2022:08:28" |
| 9 | "config-01" | "user-01" | "Prod" | "2022:08:27" |

Now I need to compare two rows of each team against their config column and say if there is a change between them. So the final response I am looking for will be,

| userid | team | configchanged |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "user-01" | "Dev" | TRUE |
| "user-01" | "QA" | FALSE |
| "user-01" | "Prod" | FALSE |

As of now I was able to reach at a point where I can see rows with same team together using this self join query,

```
select * from table t1, table t2
where t1.id <> t2.id and t1.team = t2.team and t1.userid = "user-01"
```

I need help on rest of the part.

Any help on generating a query to achieve this solution would be really helpful.

Comment: It's a little confusing that your question says 'based on createdon' , your query attempt uses id and the id in the sample does not increment with time. Please publish your table definition as text.

Comment: Coming from nosql background, I might have made mistakes there.
I used id to avoid duplicates while doing a self join. I thought of that entire query given above as a subquery, and need to do some additional things on top of that(subquery result) to achieve what I am looking for.

Comment: The reason I asked for table definition is so I can see the datatypes, indexes, engine and collation. Also your last comments seem to indicate that you can have more than 1 entry per day so is your published sample data representative?

Comment: Yeah, we will have more than one entry per day(a new record every few of hours).
The definition is like:
id: string, index
config: string
user-id: string
team: string
createdon: date

This is using aws athena(which accepts string as data type). Athena uses Presto with full standard SQL support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why this is tagged both with MySQL and Presto, but here is approach for Presto/Trino.

You can use [window functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html) (`lag` in particular to compare "current" and "previous" records) and group by. Here is a little bit more generic approach (without filtering, but that is easy to add):

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset (id, config, userid, team, createdon) as (
    values (1   , 'config-01', 'user-01', 'Dev',    '2022:08:28'),
        (2  , 'config-02', 'user-01', 'Dev',    '2022:08:27'),
        (3  , 'config-01', 'user-01', 'Dev',    '2022:08:26'),
        (4  , 'config-01', 'user-01', 'QA', '2022:08:25'),
        (5  , 'config-01', 'user-01', 'QA', '2022:08:24'),
        (6  , 'config-20', 'user-01', 'QA', '2022:08:23'),
        (7  , 'config-01', 'user-01', 'QA', '2022:08:22'),
        (8  , 'config-01', 'user-01', 'Prod','2022:08:21'),
        (9  , 'config-01', 'user-01', 'Prod','2022:08:20'),
        (10 , 'config-11', 'user-02', 'Prod','2022:08:19'),
        (11 , 'config-15', 'user-02', 'Prod','2022:08:18')
)

-- query
select userid, 
   team, 
   max_by(configchanged, createdon) configchanged -- get last change status
from (
   select *,
    config != coalesce(lag(config) over (partition by userid, team order by createdon), config) configchanged -- coalesce is used just in case there is only one row 
   from dataset
)
group by userid, team
```

Output:

| userid | team | configchanged |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user-01 | QA | false |
| user-01 | Prod | false |
| user-01 | Dev | true |
| user-02 | Prod | true |

Comment: This was presto indeed, I used mysql tag since I thought mysql developers will also be able to answer this question. BTW Thanks a lot for the answer!!

PS: Guess someone has removed mysql(and presto tag for some reason) tag. In the future, I will try not to include tags which are not really related to the question :)

Comment: @ThasmeerP was glad to help! As for the tags - it is really better to add only relevant ones) Also general `sql` should be enough to aquire attention of developers using other SQL dialects.

Comment: can we limit the number of rows partition returns, so we can only compare the latest two rows from each group of data and avoid comparing any other rows unnecessarily?

Comment: @ThasmeerP possibly you can look into ordering and using `limit` or using `row_num` window function with `where`, but not sure that it will improve performance.